# Loopback query with join

Tags: javascript, mysql, loopbackjs

in loopback, I started with this model:

```
[
  {
    "mov_id": 0,
    "mov_tipo": "string",
    "mov_valore": 0,
    "mov_causale_fk": 0,
    "mov_conto_fk": 0,
    "mov_data": "2017-10-04T09:02:19.620Z",
    "mov_note": "string",
    "mov_utente_fk": 0,
    "mov_aggiunta": "2017-10-04T09:02:19.620Z"
  }
]
```

then I added two relations, which correspond to two Foreign Keys in my MySQL database:

```
  "relations": {
    "causale_fk": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "causali",
      "foreignKey": "causale_id",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    },
    "conto_fk": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "conti",
      "foreignKey": "conto_id",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    }
  },
```

I would also like to see the fields in those models, as if I did make a query with JOIN.
it's possible??

Answer (score 0):

ok, i resolved with scope.

this is the model:

```
{
  "name": "movimenti",
  "plural": "movimenti",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "scope": {
    "include": [
      "causale_fk",
      "conto_fk"
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "mov_id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "mov_valore": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "causale_fk": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "causali",
      "foreignKey": "causale_id"
    },
    "conto_fk": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "conti",
      "foreignKey": "conto_id",
      "include": "conti"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

bye!!

Answer (score 0):

You can your to add options in your filter, and the particular option you need to set is `include`. Check [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Include-filter.html) for more details.

This is an example for you particular needs:

```
{
Model.find({include:['causale_fk','conto_fk']}, function(){});
}
```